# .htaccess retirar nome das vars do url mas deixar as vars

Tags: htaccess

Neste momento tenho os URLs:

`www.meudominio.com/?route=service&serv_name=cascais_proxima&id=1`

e

`www.meudominio.com/?route=ticket&serv_id=1&ticket=A`

mas gostaria que ficasse:

`www.meudominio.com/service/cascais_proxima`

e

`www.meudominio.com/ticket/1/A`

Há maneira de o fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tem sim ficaria da seguinte forma no .htaccess :

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pagina/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /pagina.php?route=$1&serv_name=$2&id=$3`

Que no final ficaria algo como: pagina/rota/servidor/1

Sendo o (.*) o que você quer substituir e o $[numero] a posição da URL que vc obteve e quer sobrescrever.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Desculpe mas pode ser mais explicito? O que escreveria no url para ver se resulta, no meu esemplo... Já tenho o meu .htaccess definido com esse conteudo

Comment: Não está a resultar

Comment: Para o 1º tentei: `.../service/cascais_proxima/1`, não deu

Comment: Olá Miguel, seguinte. Crie o arquivo na raiz do seu site com o conteúdo acima ajustando apenas a sua URL com o exemplo que fiz acima.